# Getting Unkown target for HPA

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, hpa

Am actually new to kubernetes, but as now am good with the terms such as deployment, pods etc.
Well i was trying an example of HPA (Horizontal pod autoscaler), and as prerequisite metrics-servers is already integrated, but after all those things am not able to see HPA working as expected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRwh7.jpg)
When execute below cmd-
Kubectl get hpa

Unknown in the target, although i have tried all my luck referring online forum but didn't got any break through
Any help would be really appreciated

Thank you

Comment: try the following, A. kubectl describe hpa # to get more info. B. Do set up manually MENU>kubernetes engine>workloads>your workload>actions>autoscale . C. check metrics agent pods. D. check at monitoring whether you have data

Comment: thanks @danyL for the input, i have cross checked although at UI am able to see the metric data such as cpu and memory utilization for my workload. but the same is not reflecting for hpa to work, also when when executed above cmd (A) it says

Comment: `the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
Events: `

Comment: Not sure but this person had a similar case where [cpu request was missing](https://www.fixes.pub/program/916208.html). you will need to translate to english.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue, fixed after adding cpu requests in my pod defination. Below points can be the reason in most of the cases

- Metric server is not installed in your kubernates cluster, you can check with command
  (kubectl get deploy,svc -n kube-system | egrep metrics-server)
- Check if you have provided resources for deployment/sts/pod definations